# Tornado. How get raw request.body?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tornado

guys. I can't get raw body data with Tornado. I do request
`curl -i localhost:8888 -d '{"a":12}'` and expect to get a string `'{"a":12}'` in request.body, but received `'{a:12}'`.
Source code:

```
import tornado.web
import tornado.ioloop

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        self.write(self.request.body)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = tornado.web.Application({
        (r"/", MainHandler)
    })
    app.listen(3000)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

curl result:

```
$ curl 127.0.0.1:3000 -i -d {"a":12}
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Server: TornadoServer/4.0.2
Content-Length: 6
Date: Thu, 22 Jan 2015 14:00:19 GMT

{a:12}
```

Python version is 3.4.2, Tornado version is 4.0.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a shell quoting issue: the shell is removing the quotes in the command `curl 127.0.0.1:3000 -i -d {"a":12}`. If you quote the argument to `-d` (which you did in the body of your question: `curl -i localhost:8888 -d '{"a":12}'`, you should get the results you expect.

Answer (score 3):

Use `self.request.connection.stream.read_bytes` to read data stream directly.

[Source](https://gist.github.com/nephics/1134964)

Comment: That gist applies to an experimental fork/branch of Tornado, not any real release. Applications should not generally access self.request.connection.stream directly.

Comment: I didn't know it's experimental, didn't check, sorry. I'm don't see why apps shouldn't use it as it's not private or protected in any way. Probably in similar manner you can access connection object in current releases of tornado.

Comment: You shouldn't access the stream directly because tornado is also reading from the same stream. In general, tornado reads the entire request before control reaches the application code, so if you try to read you'll actually read part of the *next* request. In streaming mode your request is still on the wire, but tornado is trying to read it at the same time and so you'll race with the framework.